# How to setup gitignore in root folder

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a fullstack project I want to push to github. Root folder with server and client folder. I don't want to have 2 separate gitignore files in server and client. I just want to add it to root. When i did, its not ignoring any of the files.

```
node_modules/
.env/
yarn.*
.DS_Store
```

Comment: Sure it is ... or maybe it isn't. How would we know? You have not shown the output of `git status` or any other hints of what makes you believe it isn't working. See [ask].

Comment: 2 separating gitignore files may be the best practice

Comment: @KenTsu ahhh ok thanks boss. I thought it was only one gitignore file in the root because when i see others repo, I just see it in the root and not in both folders. Lesson learned!

Comment: @torek sorry mate Ill try to be more explicit next time.

Comment: Just edit the question to show: (a) what you think should happen; (b) what does happen instead. (See the link, there's a lot of good advice there.)

Answer (score 0):

you should separate project directory into server code and client code.

```
src/
src/server
src/client
```

and make .gitignore for server and client

```
src/server/.gitignore
src/client/.gitignore
```

at last, you can extract shared gitignore into root src dir

```
src/.gitignore
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I just added gitignores to both my client and server folder. How do i go about extracting the shared gitignore into root?

Comment: comparing two gitignores, finding the same name directory, such as node_modules, adding **/node_modules into the shared gitignore file.

Comment: Check the document here(https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and you need to understand how gitignore ignores with patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Try do like this

```
**/node_modules
**/.env
```

it says the file is in any folder, with that name. so all files/folders named `node_modules` and `.env` will be ignored.

put the `.gitignore` in the root folder with the client and server folders